# How to set responsive font size in wix website

Tags: css, responsive, velo

I'm going to build wix website.
I have several headings on my site.
But some text is shown well on wide screen but not small screen.
So I would like to set font-size style using such as vw, or rem
I can find the ID of text element but I can't change the style.
Please help me with this thing.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Would you please let me know let me know more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple article to learn more about responsive design w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

It's example from there how to change font-size

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

/* If the screen size is 600px or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What I'm going to ask is not css code.
I want to know where should I put the css code and how can I make it run on Wix website?
Thank you